# Impressions of a newbie to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, new-users, fastest-gun, gamification

This is very much a discussion, and I don't expect that there will be a "right" answer to this. My objective is just to start a conversation that perhaps may improve Stack Overflow, given that I'm very grateful to this website.

For the longest time, I have been just a "lurker" to Stack Overflow, googling for information, but not contributing. Eventually I thought that was wrong, and I decided that I should contribute to the website. As such, I recently tried my best to start giving answers. As you can see by my reputation, I actually managed to help some people, which made me feel good. :-)

However, I noticed two things that made me concerned about Stack Overflow:

- First, there seem to be some people who see this as just a game. As such, they jump on questions, and give answers in seconds, even if they are imprecise, and edit those later. It means that if you try to craft an answer, to make sure of what you're saying, and adding links and code snippets, etc., you're usually beaten by somebody else and your answer is ignored.
- On the other side of the spectrum, you can notice that some people are not following the "be nice" policy as much. So, even if you say that you're not sure about something (for example, it's not even an answer, it's just a commentary) or if you make an honest mistake, some people will engage in name-calling and call you an idiot, a vandal, nonsensical, etc. You can flag those people, of course, but eventually it becomes tiresome, and you don't feel like answering any more.

Between those two issues, you get stuck: if you take your time to craft your answer, somebody else will beat you. But if you go too fast and possibly make a small mistake, then you risk hearing some not nice words. Those two issues combined, in my opinion, constitute an incentive for people to **not** contribute to Stack Overflow.

Any thoughts on this? Am I wildly off the mark? Is there a way that those issues can be minimized besides what Stack Overflow already does? Is this something that we just have to live with?

**Update:** first of all, let me say that I appreciate very much all the comments that were made. I'll certainly take the advice you guys gave (particularly, @Oleg, I like what you said, who cares what names some random stranger writes? :-) ).

However, I need to clarify one thing about my question: this is not about *me*. This question is about other people that may reach the same conclusions that I reached, but differently than me may have decide to give up on Stack Overflow. Feel free to say that I'm the *only* person who ever reached these conclusions. :-) But if you think it's possible that more people reached the same conclusions that I did, what could Stack Overflow do to mitigate that problem?

**Update II:** I just saw a Stack Overflow post that talks about part of the problem that I brought in my original post. The bad aspect of this is that, if it reached that point, then the issue of being a hostile community is truly a problem. However, the good aspect of this is that the problem has been recognized and there are people working to solve it.

Comment: *for example, it's not even an answer, it's just a commentary* - Be sure to post those comments as comments, not answers. Otherwise you risk getting your post flagged as Not An Answer. Note that when the community reviews those flags the system suggests leaving a comment explaining what's wrong with your post.

Comment: *if you take your time to craft your answer, somebody else will beat you* A well crafted answer is better than just being first. If it is useful in general, not just to the OP, then others should up vote even if you don't get the accept mark. You can also focus on older questions without answers.

Comment: As far as the rude comments go, someone was looking at automating flagging those but I can't recall how far they got with that.

Comment: The game is definitely an important part of this site, it's addicting and that's what makes it so successful, you need to either play better, play differently or ignore it and just concentrate on writing quality answers without worrying about the points. Couple of related links: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30910

Comment: As to your second complaint, nobody ever called me any names the most offensive thing anybody ever said to me was that I should concern a doctor which I should've flagged but I just ignored, so I don't know how you managed to find people who called you an idiot this is not the rule. Just flag or learn to ignore it, you shouldn't care about what name some stranger on the internet called you.

Comment: @BSMP: Are you familiar with the Queen bot that displays its output in the [SOBotics chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics)? If not, check out the output from its Heat Detector to see that its abilities are coming along.

Comment: Totally agree on second point - when you make a mistake posting any comment to a question OP frequently "will engage in name calling and call you an idiot, a vandal, nonsensical, etc". (let's say this comment is a joke)

Comment: *"For the longest time, I have been just a "lurker" to StackOverflow, Googling for information but not contributing. Eventually I thought that was wrong"* - IMO that is the one and only good way to introduce yourself to Stack Overflow, well done that you showed such restraints.

Comment: @Gimby: The only good way? I'm sad now. I avoided SO for the longest time because I considered it an evil thing that stole all the attention from more thoughtful gatherings of experts and replaced them with a silly system encouraging the regurgitation of ill-researched, platitudinous drivel as fast as possible to lazy people for virtual points. But eventually I thought that was wrong. :-)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: I must have missed those “thoughtful gatherings of experts”, as most of the time when I googled for a problem, I found similar problem descriptions without useful answers, until Stackoverflow entered the scene and provided real answers, Once I realized that I end up at Stackoverflow anyway, I started looking at Stackoverflow in the first place (which seems to be what Google does nowadays anyway). The good non-Q&A expert sites (like Blogs) often get more attention today, because they get linked from Stackoverflow…

Comment: @Holger: of course -- SO is the best Q&A site by a long shot, especially for people *asking questions*. Part of this is the low barrier to entry, offered by things being easy to Google here. The whole point of places that aren't as easy to find or as welcoming for newbies is that it keeps out the newbies. (The relative merits of these approaches need not be discussed here; in particular, I'm not saying SO shouldn't be welcoming to newbies or that it's bad for doing that!)

Comment: If anyone is rude then just ignore them - picture them as a 40-something guy, living on pizza at home with his mum, able to give essays and lectures on obscure computer science subject and yet forgets to wash. As for rushing to answer - if you really know and want to help someone who asks a question, then just try and give the best answer you can. Even if it's not the first, try and make it the best.

Comment: The people who are quick to answer will not be the ones with the piles Revival and Necromancer badges.

Comment: As a similar complaint as the OP, it seems that when I ask a question to which I can't find the answer to (neither on SO nor Google) it gets downvoted. Questions from 6-8 years ago, with 0 research, something that 1 google search would answer, have hundreds of upvotes.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284676/do-i-have-to-use-malloc-every-time-i-return-a-pointer vs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc

Comment: This is exactly why I don't contribute to Stack Overflow.  I've had more luck on other sites on the Stack Exchange network (especially the non-technical ones).

Comment: @deviantfan How much rep would you say is needed in order to stop being a 'low-reputation user'?

Comment: @Oleg There is no specific limit where it stops changing - more rep is always less problems with users here.

Comment: @xyious You might want to look at the difference in time, that highly upvoted question is 8 years old, so 1) it is from a time when SO was new and it was easy to ask simple questions that hadn't been asked before and 2) it has had 8 years to attract those votes (eg because someone landed on it through Google and appreciated it).

Comment: @Discoverer98 Welcome!, I had a similar experience as you and my solution was to [escape](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314406/can-i-sit-under-my-oak-tree-or-do-i-need-to-go-on-rep-hunt/314415#314415) under a low-traffic tag, this does not mean you will not get rep (just pass nice answer and give it some time) and also there is a lot of other fun on SO as keeping it clean from non answers, rude comments, plagiarized answers , bad edits etc. My advice is to find a corner you like and have fun in that corner, true there is lot of mess on SO but heck that's just how internet works.

Comment: People can be super rude on this website. I just don't take it personally. I'm here to learn

Comment: I remember that my first questions on SO were much less well received than the later ones. I attribute it to two things: I improved my foo and there is a prejudice against newcomers. Not sure how much each thing accounted for. Actually a double blind study would probably reveal the existence and extent of such a prejudice.

Comment: My opinion. Don’t try to beat people to the punch, especially if you’re not a guru. Instead look to improve existing questions. My 10k rep is from improving older questions with fresh or better answers. Ive also gains a decent amount of rep by asking new questions and then answering them myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I never experienced the problems you see. That's probably because

1. I don't read and write in high-frequency tags like [c++] or [javascript]
2. I try to avoid answering questions that are immediately answerable. In 99.99% these questions are worthless to other users beside the one posting it. Usually many users skilled with the language could answer it adds no value to them. I only down-vote or flag such answers for closing if I find reasons. Sometimes I leave a comment what's missing to be a proper question. Most of the time I ignore such questions.

I try to answer question that either address are larger audience or that are have not received an answer withing half a day.

I see the problem of SO more in help vampires and rep hunters. Further reading about this topic:

- [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)
- [How to deal with fast (but bad) answerers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345182/how-to-deal-with-fast-but-bad-answerers)
- [What is the best way to deal with "rep-whoring"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151320/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-rep-whoring)
- Social study on SO users:
  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/2799037

Comment: Your last bullet point ("Social study on SO users") actually clarified to me exactly what's going on, hence why I marked this as the answer. Everything in computing tends to follow a cycle of coming up, enjoying great success, start showing signs of decline and faster than you imagine becoming irrelevant (remember MySpace? ;-) ) Perhaps that's what's happening to SO, and my question, in the end, was just a way for me to grieve. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: I find it hard to say that rep hunters are part of the problem when the lure of reputation points is the name of the game though; they're more of an expected byproduct of the way the site works. Likely you are in fact referring to the Fastest Guns in the West, the damaging subset of the rep hunter clan. Other than that, nice answer.

Answer (score 48):

> Well, you can say that the answer is wrong, or imprecise. But saying that it is "misleading" is, frankly, rude.

You did not give any concrete evidence of your experience at SO, but this comment seems very relevant.  I found it back on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46454934/17034) you posted in the [c++] tag.  There were 3 comments from SO users, all of whom pointed out that your answer was not likely to be helpful and giving guidance on how to make it better.

Fair warning on posting in [c++], it is a tag that is visited by contributors that have been living and breathing C++ for 15 years or more.  They do know the many traps that the language sets out for an inexperienced programmer very well, mostly by falling into them themselves.  Very quick answers are entirely normal, getting a solution to a programming problem in a matter of minutes is certainly what made SO famous.  Contributors tend to focus on the immediate problem first, then spend some time editing the post to make it more generally interesting.  That might *look* like they "jump on questions", it is not exactly the right impression.  They just know it.

Then there is the universal problem of trying to help somebody in the amount of space that a comment allows.  Which is not often enough and does beget the kind of problems that high ranking government officials experience when they think that posting policy in a Twitter post is a good idea.  There are just too many ways to attach too much meaning to an isolated word, like "misleading" in this case.  The post was misleading in the sense that the OP might easily end up chasing the wrong solution for an hour and not get anywhere.  Assuming that it was *intentionally* misleading, no, nobody does that.  There is just no point to that, trolling is not an SO problem.

You'll be ahead and get the benefit of contributing to SO, learning how to be a better programmer, when you can deal with getting it wrong.  In general important, if you always get it right then you are not learning anything and the site quickly gets boring.  That can only work well if SO users tell you how it is wrong.  That is *not* criticism, it is assistance.  It is *helpful* to you.  But if you can't see it as help or beneficial to you then you are unlikely to enjoy your time here.  Not entirely unusual btw.  Just keep in mind that mistakes are *very* easy to fix, just delete the post.  Next one surely will be better.

Comment: What are you quoting exactly?

Comment: I posted a link to the post, just look at the comments under it.

Comment: Ah, I see. The way you put it as the first thing looked like it's a comment from this page.

Comment: Hans, thanks for your long explanation. If I may, I have two points I would like to make: the first one is that, as I clarified later, this is not about my experience on SO. Rather, this is about what other people may see when they come to SO. The second point is that I actually agree with you: I have no problem whatsoever being pointed that I'm wrong, or that I'm taking things in the wrong direction. However, the _language_ used in that is important: you can both say "You're a misleader!" or you can say "I think that you are taking this in a wrong direction."

Comment: Just to further my point, the _way_ that you say things can make all the difference between a person _learning_ something or a person _leaving_ a place. People are not machines: the way things are communicated is important, notwithstanding what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: Final point: I actually heard from a couple of my colleagues to not _waste time_ posting at SO, because people there were rude. I went ahead anyway, but because I value SO a lot, I want to bring focus to that. And, once again, I appreciate very much your words. :-)

Comment: Hmya, language is not important.  We use English words to express technical ideas, uttered quite often by SO users for whom English is not their first language.  The vast majority having no idea whatsoever that a non-technical word has baggage attached.  So if you want to find back rudeness then you'll have no trouble finding some, short and direct comments can easily be candidates.  Assuming good intentions first is pretty important, and when somebody tries to help you then there is no lack of such intention.  If the word overrides the intention then you have a problem to solve.

Comment: I think we will have to agree to disagree on this. I believe that language is important: for example, wars were fought because of the language used between countries, hence why diplomats speak in such convoluted ways. Furthermore, I would argue that your own argument shows that. As you said, we use _English_ to express our ideas. In other words, you are already mindful of what language you use: if you didn't care that you were talking in German, for example, it wouldn't matter that you were saying something that's absolutely right. :-) But I'm fine with different opinions in this. :-)

Comment: There's a difference between being rude and being frank/direct. Unfortunately the two seem to be often conflated. Many times, complaints  or perceptions of rudeness actually stem from the alleged offender not delivering their criticism wrapped in pleasantries or in a friendly/encouraging/nurturing tone to soften the blow (so to speak) that a person inevitably feels (to differing extents) upon receiving criticism, rather than from the alleged offender actually being rude. Keep an open mind and as Hans Passant said, assume good intention.

Comment: I agree with this question & many of the comments as advice, but they are missing the point of the question that people may be driven away because they do not have the advised way of looking at things.

Comment: I don't think it's useful or fair to dig through the OP's question/answer history to pick out examples of the OP being treated *curtly*, to refute the idea that new users are by-and-large treated *rudely*.  Just look at any low-scoring questions in the tag of your choice, and you'll find numerous instances of comments that are both frank *and* rude. I was able to find 5-6 particularly egregious examples in under a minute.  "You need to be able to do the math by hand with pencil and paper before you try to teach a computer how to do it.", for example.

Comment: @Discoverer98 You say language is important, yet you paraphrase a comment you got as "you're a misleader" when what was really said was "this answer is misleading". I think this demonstrates that you're taking the comments too personally. No one's accusing you of being someone who deliberately or repeatedly misleads other people. The comment simply means that in that particular case, the solution proposed in your answer may lead someone to believe that it fixes their problem while it doesn't really address the root cause of the issue.

Comment: @alex I don't see any problem with "You need to be able to do the math by hand with pencil and paper before you try to teach a computer how to do it." sounds like good advice, people need to stop taking things personally and be offended by any little thing. If you came here, asked a question, got an opinion from an expert that you lack some basic math skills, say thanks and go acquire them.

Comment: Hi, @Oleg! Let me offer a counterpoint: not only there is no precise definition of what is a "little thing" but also the "thing" evolves over time. In the past, it was perfectly fine in schools that, if a kid got a math answer wrong, he would be spanked with a wooden utensil on the hand. Today, that would be considered unthinkable, and it could end in jail time. Same thing here: what someone may consider no big deal may actually be pretty bad by another one. The solution is just to follow SO's policy of "be nice": it's better to err on the side of being too nice than the opposite.

Comment: @Discoverer98 True but the same applies to niceness. I don't see anything in the aforementioned comment that doesn't conform to the "be nice" policy. I'm not going to wrap everything I say in some phony pleasantries, I don't like it and in fact don't find it nice at all. Also in addition to \@m69's explanation you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620680/why-doesnt-volatile-in-java-5-ensure-visibility-from-another-thread#comment76358804_10620680) for an alternative way to respond to someone who says your post is deceptive and misleading.

Comment: Hi, @Oleg! Let me answer to what you said with two points, if I may. First, I think that you're posing a false dichotomy: the opposite of "rude" is not "phony pleasantries". We shouldn't go overboard either. :-) Second, I appreciate what you're telling me about how to respond to things like that, but the original point of this question was to avoid that we have to do that to _everybody else_ who takes a look at SO. I'm fine with SO, the problem is how to avoid that other people leave the site because they think people here are rude.

Comment: @Oleg If you tell your coworker to "learn how to do math with a pencil and paper" because they asked you why your code doesn't run, are you really going to be able to convince your boss that you were just being friendly? Would you personally take that as constructive criticism?

Comment: @Discoverer98 No, it's false only for the same person, when things are measured on the same scale. If something completely polite and normal to me seems rude to you and something completely normal to you seems like phony pleasantries to me the 2 are in direct opposition. All we can do is respect each other, claiming one of us is right and expecting the other to change will be very unproductive. As to what to do, things are constantly being done, some people will see your question and the answers and hopefully it will help them. Pleasing everybody is simply not possible.

Comment: @alex Yes, I see no problem telling the original full quote to a coworker. Your later quote is completely different and rude.

Answer (score 30):

I think, your main mistake is to try to answer questions you already know or expect to receive dozens of answers within the first seconds. More than often, such questions, answerable within seconds, are actually questions which should be closed, e.g. as duplicate or “simple typographical error”, etc.

Besides that, ask yourself why you are trying to answer such questions. If for the reputation, well, you already know that’s difficult due to the competition. If for helping someone, well, you already know that the questioner is about to get lots of help within the next seconds.

On the other hand, there are [1,819,709 (±1,000) questions having no answer at all](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers). I’m sure, there are question you could answer without fearing competition from some of the “fastest gun in the West” guys. You don’t have to start with five year old questions, even questions a few hours old usually don’t get the attention of those gamers.

Mind the existence of the tags to filter the questions according to [your fields of interest or special knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) to find questions possibly only you can answer (ok, that’s an exaggeration).

When not gaming for being the “fastest gun in the West” you have the time needed to write an answer that has high quality right when being published. You might also find out that flaws in your answer are perceived differently when there’s no crowd around trying to advertise their own answer. People hoping for an answer for a longer time appreciate honest attempts to answer their question much more. And if there are flaws, they can be fixed.

Comment: Your first link gives me back a 404.

Comment: @Pac0: you mean [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/no-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/no-answer)? Works perfectly fine for me and I don’t see what could be causing problems.

Comment: Though to be completely honest, those questions with no answer are mostly (from what I've seen, and I tried to dig for gold there) questions that were bad, asked for improvement in the comments (unclear, no MCVE etc.) and got no response. Although they get cleaned, they keep popping up. It's extremely rare that you would be able to answer something the rest of the community couldn't. +1 for separating the real life gain from the internet points game.

Comment: @Holger yes exactly... I just double checked... Seems some kind of bug with cache servers. I will post a bug report accordingly. Thanks for confirmation the link is valid.

Comment: @user1803551: well, *every* question starts its life as a question without answers and if it doesn’t get answers within seconds from the gamers, it will be in that list until it gets actual answers. So they can’t be *all* crap. Well, there might be a lot of noise, so I can only recommend (again) to care about topic filters. High quality questions tend to have relevant tags, so filtering for tags not within [the top 20](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) can lead to interesting results. I already managed to write accepted or highly upvoted answers to several months old questions.

Comment: Just about my 404 on the link, just written a bug report if anyone experiences the same : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357508/some-stack-overflow-valid-links-give-me-404

Comment: @Holger I agree with the noise level, I said "mostly" myself. And my observation is *after* filtering for [java]. Still, it depends how much you're willing to dig there; you spend more time on this site and have a larger skillset than me so you might benefit more. All I'm saying is that combating the FGITW is not as simple as going into that list and starting to shoot answers.

Comment: @user1803551: that’s why I said, filtering for tags *not within the [top 20](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular)*; if you look at the linked page, you’ll see that `[java]` is the second-most used tag (used 1,321,622 times), so obviously, filtering for `[java]` only is almost as having no filter at all as even the low quality questions have that tag when even remotely related to java. High quality questions usually have more specific tags. Obviously, I have started as a beginner too and satisfaction came only after deciding not to do gambling, but focus on interesting questions…

Comment: I really dislike these blanket statements that all questions that are easy to answer are inherently closeable. Sure it is likely that such questions have been asked before in many cases, but I don't think that is the rule. I also think attributing the typo reason like that is less than useful. We need more specificity with how we're throwing these close reasons around in meta posts because it is really making it seem like the point of Stack Overflow is to close questions, which it isn't and that is very discouraging.

Comment: I just want to say, @Holger, that I very much appreciate your piece of advice. I'll give that a try. :-)

Comment: @Tiny Giant: “more than often” is a different statement than “all”. Besides that, the typo close reason is well explained in the suggested close reason text itself. There is *no worth to future readers*, as typo based question are impossible to find, even if someone having exactly the same error is searching for it. That doesn’t prevent you from helping the questioner. Just leave a comment. But there is no sense in keeping typo based questions on stackoverflow, nor inviting more users to write even more answers explaining the same trivial typo.

Answer (score 2):

> It means that if you try to craft an answer, to make sure of what you're saying, and adding links and code snippets, etc., you're usually beaten by somebody else and your answer is ignored.

Even if you would mimic the rapid prototyping style of others, instead of polishing your answer secretly, you still would face the risk of essentially duplicate answers and a waste of effort. That is certainly a drawback and a better way of collaboration between answerers (like seeing how many others are trying to write an answer currently) would be appreciated.

> ..even if you say that you're not sure about something (for example, it's not even an answer, it's just a commentary) or if you make an honest mistake, some people will engage in name-calling and call you an idiot, a vandal, nonsensical, etc. You can flag those people, of course, but eventually it becomes tiresome

Hm, I have not really seen name-calling and calling others idiots often and in the cases I have moderators usually were really quick in deleting these comments and suspending the pundits for some time. I don't feel intimidated a bit, but I can imagine that newcomers may be impacted more by it. I wonder though what SO could do more than it already does in that regard? You will always have it to some extent in every internet community.

> Those two issues combined, in my opinion, constitute an incentive for people to not contribute to Stack Overflow.

I agree, although I'm not sure how big this incentive actually is. Also the question remains what else SO could do about it?

> ...what could Stack Overflow do to mitigate that problem?

Not much more I guess. Adding functionality to let people know if answers are already in writing and immediate, consistent deletion and suspensions of name-calling incidents. I cannot think of much more of what one could do.

Also quite important:

What you could do though? Adopt the rapid prototyping answering style or concentrate on older, unanswered questions and getting a thick skin and just flagging (not answering, or only shortly answering incidents) bad stuff. Or, if this is not possible, just not contributing to SO. Don't do it, if you do not feel comfortable doing so! It should be fun. ;)

Comment: Not saying I'm against it or that it will necessary happen but showing how many others are trying to answer might only make people to post even more hastily written and prototype answers thus exacerbating the problem.

Comment: @Oleg Depends a bit what the problem is. Is the problem that people work in parallel or is the problem that people publish their premature work and then iterate on it?

Answer (score 0):

SO can be downright depressing sometimes. As someone who doesn't always have the thickest skin who kinda pours everything I got into some of my answers, I go from being in love with the site to hating it back and forth.

I haven't really encountered the name calling you have encountered. Even the people who disagreed with me and down-voted but took the time to comment were generally civil, at least on the surface. But I have gotten into some debates with people in the past on engineering topics, probably because I'm deeply opinionated and some of my thoughts are out there as one into data-oriented design. For example, I actually believe it's superior in some cases for dependencies to flow towards data rather than abstractions, as in the case of entity-component systems often used by game engines. However, that violates the DIP aspect of SOLID, and naturally a number of people are going to disagree with me.

But I have noticed a pattern typically when I disagree with someone and they down-vote me and we have our little civil debate that, minutes after, many of my unrelated answers get down-voted, and this time with no comments about why I got down-voted. And I don't know for sure if it's the person who debated me who did that or if it was just some kind of coincidence, but that's the part that drives me crazy and paranoid. Maybe someone else just saw our disagreements in the comments and decided to down-vote my other answers. I have no idea who did that or why, and it feels so incredibly spiteful to be doing that just because we disagree on some engineering ideas.

As for the issue about the fastest guns in the west, I see it as an inevitability and don't really blame those people. I'm even guilty of often doing it myself but not to rack up points. It's because sometimes I invest a whole lot of time in an answer believing my answer to be great and potentially a canonical one, only to have it down-voted from people who give me no feedback, and for seemingly bizarre reasons. I've even been down-voted on questions for which I have 30+ years of experience on the subject and have published books about it, and then I get down-voted. And my immediate response is like, *"Wait, did I actually write something wrong? Could I be incorrect about this?"* And so I double-check with other resources, colleagues, and everything and everyone agrees with my answer, but I still get down-voted. I even got down-voted answering a question related to a software whose development I lead (though I didn't mention this since I'm trying to preserve some anonymity). Ironically, I likewise sometimes get many up-votes on answers for which I had far more limited experience and wasn't nearly as sure if it was such a good answer as the ones that got a down-vote.

So these days I don't try to provide an elaborate answer until it starts getting some up-votes because I can't predict the pattern of what is and isn't going to be deemed by a good answer by such an unpredictable group. Then if I do get the up-votes, I'll keep editing it and editing it to try to make it better and better. Otherwise I fear spending a great deal of time and energy providing an answer which is just going to get lost in the shuffle because some people didn't like the answer for whatever reason and decided to down-vote it.

For newbies I imagine the site would often feel extremely hostile, even if there's no name-calling whatsoever, with the aggressive moderation. I used to participate in that for a while, joining a tag-team of people coordinating close votes and such, until I realized the whole futility of it. It's like trying to filter out low-quality content from the entire internet -- just absolutely futile. What isn't as futile is putting a spotlight on the quality content, though even that is tough when the site seems schizophrenic about what it considers quality content where some of the highest-rated questions might have been closed if someone else looked at it first.

One of the things that cheers me up sometimes is just write answers or questions for which I have no emotional investment whatsoever, so it doesn't really matter if they get down-voted. As an example, I've bountied off thousands of points before asking some basic questions for which I already knew the answer, but to make it interesting, I requested the answers be written in Haiku. And that really cheered me up for a while but then the mods closed and deleted those questions too and it got all boring and depressing again.

Comment: Do you appreciate questions and answers Stack Overflow having quite a high standard? (If they do not, in your opinion, then: *would* you appreciate ...?)

Comment: @usr2564301 Do you think the majority of questions on SO adhere to a high standard? Mostly I think it's a sea of very basic questions which are kind of borderline RTFM vein. I don't mind that though; I only wish there were more interesting questions and answers in addition to those, and all the moderation over the years doesn't seem to have encouraged more interesting questions being asked or encouraged more interesting answers to be provided.

Comment: What I mean is: without that "aggressive moderation", as you call it, it would be much worse. *Much* worse.

Comment: How much content gets deleted vs. just closed? Complete spam and flagging is helpful, but often I find so many interesting things closed... duplicates that aren't quite duplicate, things marked as broad or opinionated which could have yielded some very interesting answers. Mostly I feel like some really interesting opportunities are missed when the moderation closes a question which could have yielded some genuinely interesting answers... I look at those which are closed, and then look at the 200 other questions which are like, "How do I do this super basic thing?" and it's depressing.

Comment: @usr2564301 Here's an example of an utter crap question which I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134218/is-multiple-assignment-expression-a-123-b-456-c-789-well-defined... and just minutes ago, in spite of it being closed 3 years ago with an apology at the top for my brain fart, someone decided to down-vote it. Why would someone do that? How spiteful, and I'm going paranoid. Is it because someone doesn't like my meta post here? Did you do it? I don't understand why people are stalking me and holding grudges against me. I had my little vulgar outburst but only after many repeated...

Comment: ... instances of this sort of thing happening. And also why isn't this question deleted? It's utter crap. It's apparently not cleaning the site up to leave it around... it's instead generating new down-votes 3 years later.

Comment: I don't care at all about rep and score.. I just don't understand why people are stalking me and down-voting things like this -- the mean-spiritedness... and it's that seeming hostility which is bugging me lately. And for beginners, this site must be totally daunting and scary and merciless. I have a feeling I made someone hate me because lately with all the slow traffic and boring content, I've been looking for older questions to answer. And on some I ended up inadvertently getting my answer accepted which caused someone else to lose points...

Comment: ... and maybe I upset people that way. But it wasn't my intention to steal points from them, I just wanted to answer questions I found very interesting because most of the questions are so (yawn) boring!!!