# The /questions/no-answer URL is not accessible for everyone

Tags: support, new-nav, 404-not-found

When I go to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/no-answer

I get a 404 page !

[image]

I already have [confirmation from other user that this link is valid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357502/479251), so I investigated a bit in the Chrome console. I saw this :

[image]

The culprit *seems* to be a request to some cache server `151.101.1.69`

---

Edit : If I try to follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered , I don't have any problem.

I checked, and the same cache server `151.101.1.69` is used, only that it gives 200 OK response for this link.

Comment: The link is invalid for me also. Are you sure it should be valid?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth apparently the poster of [this answer to some meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357502/479251) can browse it. (see comments)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered works for me, if you're looking for questinos with no answers

Comment: @ivarni : it works for me too. Does the link I reported works for you, or do you have a 404 as well ?

Comment: The `no-answer` link seems to be working here... so... either fixed or some localised temporary hiccough I guess?

Comment: I'm still getting nothing, both on FF 56 logged in, and on Edge logged out, from the Netherlands.

Comment: Switzerland here

Comment: @Pac0 404 on the no-answer link. I suppose success rate may vary due to caching.

Comment: @JonClements <s>could it perhaps be a high-rep privilege? 20k+ or something like that?</s> Verified with a low-rep user and they can access it.

Comment: @Stijn - since it seems to be a simple alias to https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered , I would find that quite cheap a reward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/no-answer works for me. I only have 191 reputation, so its definately not a high reputation privilege.

Comment: @pac0 `/questions/no-answer` is definitively not an alias to `/unanswered`. They give extremely different results

Comment: Although this is Meta, the rules don't change: the answer does not belong in the question, and you should not change the question after the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 23):

That page points to one of the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) filters. See this screenshot, [courtesy of Journeyman Geek](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6389363#6389363):

> [image: screenshot of new-nav filter]

So when you don't have the new-nav enabled, you cannot visit the page.

Comment: Good catch. So I was spoiled the new feature by following that other link...

Comment: Ow just read : '2015'. Not so new beta feature, apparently.

Comment: @Pac0 the feature is currently on-hold, actually.

Comment: It’s a really strange thing that the front-end (UI, presentation, whatever) determines the availability of a URL. I changed the link in my answer to [https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) which interestingly works for *both* navigation variants, though I’m always surprised that this inconsistent mixture of path and query works at all.