# Honor downvotes on answers with badges

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, badges

Downvoting is an essential part of Stack Overflow to me. It helps to [slow down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345182/2799037) [fastest guns in the west](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308302/2799037), moves bad answers down the page, encourages to improve / delete incomplete / wrong answers, and helps to get rid of garbage.

Downvotes on answers are not honored. I propose to introduce badges for five downvotes on answers (bronze), 250 downvotes on answers (silver), and 5000 downvotes on answers (gold).

Downvotes on answers cost one reputation point each, so if someone is gaming for the gold badge, it will cost 5k rep—an unlikely scenario.

Proposals for suitable badge names are welcome as answers ([so that they can be downvoted, of course!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SchmuckBait)).

Comment: *it will cost 5k rep* ... only if you cast those votes on answers that in the end don't get deleted. I assume users down vote stuff that is not useful, not to crank up their stats or, if this gets implemented, their badges.

Comment: You mean, honor downvotes WITH COMMENT, right?

Comment: @rene That's just the point. If you downvote answers that get deleted, you're probably not gaming the system. Downvoting good answers that never get deleted (which people shouldn't do) will cost 5k rep, but downvoting bad answers that get deleted (which people should do) won't cost much.

Comment: @DonaldDuck yeah, that is true. My comment wasn't meant to criticize the proposal, just to clarify. Your comment better convey's my idea though.

Comment: @Cœur No, no he doesn’t.

Comment: Erm, how do I opt out of this?  I don't feel particularly inclined to assist some horseshoe who needs one moar to get his scrap of html.  But surely I'm missing the point.  What is the point?

Comment: The point is to encourage people to cast more downvotes on answers, @Hans. Although badges are just scraps of HTML, they do seem to be pretty effective motivators for many of our users.

Comment: Hmya @Cody, it was rhetorical.  Why not remove the DV penalty?  Why not award badges for upvotes instead?  Did you ever need a badge to DV anything?  What kind of users do?  90% of the time I UV a good answer and meh a bad one.  If the answer is a true time-waster, costing the reader an hour of his life, then I DV.  We don't have enough posts that show how to *not* do it.  A bad answer is an excellent motivator to post a better one, that's just not necessary when it is DVed.  Obligatory [xkcd link](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: Seems to me that you should only get credit towards the badge if you downvote an answer that is subsequently deleted. On the other hand, too many downvotes on answers that don't get deleted should result in suspension of the downvote privilege.

Comment: @Cœur: No, he doesn't mean WITH COMMENTS.  [**Nor should comments be mandatory on downvotes.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes)

Comment: @rene "it will cost 5k rep ... only if you cast those votes on answers that in the end don't get deleted." Interesting, but what is your stance on downvoting *wrong* answers? Based on what I read about the flagging criteria, it looks like wrong answers can't be deleted, only non-answers, so votes on wrong answers would just cost rep.

Comment: @user3386109 That doesn't really make sense.  There are valid reasons to downvote a non-delete-worthy answer, the most common one being that it's [factually incorrect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/7496073).

Comment: I have some scraps of HTML that I'm not using.  Anyone want them?

Comment: Send me few @DawoodibnKareem please....

Comment: @jrh well,  wrong answers (better: a not useful answer) can be deleted by 20K-ers when they are at -3. But on answers that were helpful to a lot of people (aka lots of upvotes) it can take a while to have it removed with votes, sometimes with the help of Meta. But there are answers that are wrong but never end-up nuked, maybe also because wrong answers can be helpful: *awesome, so that is not how to do it, have an upvote, I learned something today* or other reasonings to vote. So, yes, some of my votes cost me rep and that is unlikely to ever return. Not that it is important.

Comment: @rene: you are close to it, but not entirely. There are dead-wrong answers having tons of upvotes, because they looked good and a lot of people vote based on that without ever trying the solution. When users with more understanding (or time) show up, it requires enough of them having the privilege to downvote and no fear of the reputation loss to compensate for the upvotes that costed nothing. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015039/2711488) got 51 upvotes and 30 downvotes and you can see that it took more than a year before the first comment told that it doesn’t work.

Comment: @Holger I agree that such answers exist. But I'm not convinced that such badges will be able to resolve that issue. Those questions would be rarely visited, and even then most users would find the first helpful answer and move on. It would be rare to have users to scroll all the way down, and notice a bad answer, and decide to downvote on that.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah: I’m not the one who made that proposal. But it looks like a good starting point for discussing a well-known issue. It’s understandable why upvotes are cheaper than downvotes on Stackoverflow, on the other hand, having *free* upvotes and costly downvotes combines in a bad way with the little attention span of the majority of the crowd…

Comment: If you want me to downvote more, please give me the possibility to cast more than one vote per answer/question. Sometimes I would happily spends dozens of rep to be able to downvote some *)@*(%$ into oblivion. And I don't even need a badge for it!

Comment: I have always considered this 1 rep-point DV system flawed. If an answer is plain wrong, it should get downvoted, comma. The only reason why most of them never get downvoted is that people don't want to lose one point rep. [explanations like the one here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251610/why-does-downvoting-an-answer-cost-reputation-while-questions-not) are NOT explaining anything to me about the Why it costs 1 point. Half way to solve this would be to at least let people having a certain rep threshold (or a tag bronze badge) to downvote the answers for free.

Comment: Assuming you sincerely find an answer not useful, what will determine `gaming for the gold badge`? A Person with a different understanding and opinion to yours? or a bot, god knows they are crap and never work (see YouTube or STEAM bots for great examples of broken automation)? You can't punish someone "assuming" to think their reasons are of bad intend or farming badges.

Comment: There is also the opposite where people downvote a quick answer and never come back to re-do their vote ones clarifications were added, resulting in useful answers having more downvotes than upvotes. What then? Would it be that at the time those downvotes initially were cast they were "correct" but after a small edit was made within the 5min window, clarifying the answer, "something" then retro fits the -5k rep to all downvoters? - Only being devils advocate with the possible issue a drastic "punishment" like that can have. In the end, nobody will risk a downvote at such high possible cost.

Comment: @Fran That's desired. Fasted gun in the west is not what we want. And having both up- and down-votes results still in positive rep gain.

Comment: @user3386109 The fasted gun in the west might be spot on. Point being, you can't possible know the motivation or reasoning for someone else's downvote and for all intend and purposes they are in their mind 100% true to themselves in downvoting. So who is that "process/person" to say otherwise and decide to punish them with deducting 5k rep? People will stop downvoting even if they would be right, making downvotes potentially meaningless? IMHO. I know I wouldn't waste my time downvoting if I might log in to a -5k penalty, too much headache.

Comment: @user3386109 and if "Fastest Gun" isn't wanted on SO, then disable voting until the 5min editing Cooldown is over IMHO.

Comment: I'd exchange 5k for a gold badge anytime :D

Comment: @usr1234567. Your question seems to assume that downvoting is effective in tackling the problems it is intended to deal with. Without providing hard evidence, it amounts to little more than an opinion poll. Downvoting is inherently negative. It takes something away from both the donor and the recipient. Also, it lacks the accountability and checks and balances that other activities like flagging have. You need 1000 rep just to see how many downvotes have been cast. We should not be handing out rewards for activities that provide so little constructive feedback to users.

Answer (score 41):

We sort of have a badge to encourage people to at least cast the first downvote, called ["critic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic), which recent awarded list surprise me, since most of those are less than 500 reputation users. Also, like everything in life, we would like a courter balance for these badges, the same critic has ["supporter"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter).

I don't think the problem is that people don't down vote enough, is that people don't vote enough and prefer to use up votes instead of down votes because loss aversion, which causes the skewness. If you see anonymous voting you will notice that only 62% of [all casted votes are upvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/738343), compared to the [88% of all the users votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/738346) (this number is obviously skewed, since up voting is a 15 rep privilege, meanwhile down voting is 125 one), which makes evident that the play field isn't actually level.

You want to motivate people to down vote more? Make downvoting the same as upvoting and I'm pretty sure that the numbers would approach the 6:4 ratio rather than the current 9:1 in couple years.

Comment: "Critic" is also awarded for downvoting a question, isn't? Downvoting might seem to be negative. Offering a badge would signal that it is ok to downvote. Similar to fouling in basketball, to some extend it is not dirty but part of the game.

Comment: It's a bronze badge, it's expected that mostly newbies get it.

Comment: I tend not to downvote things (unless they are really really bad and wrong) because I don't want to be mean.

Comment: @Yvonne You don't have to care about the feelings of the user, just as the user (generally) doesn't care if he posts bad content. Also remember you are not judging a user or his efforts, you are judging the usefulness and quality of the post.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow It's not mean to downvote. It's part of the game. A badge might help clarifying this.

Comment: @Yvonne agree. I rather comment and tell them why it won't work or what is wrong. If they don't fix it within a reasonable time I downvote.

Comment: What's the difference between the two queries you linked to?

Comment: @DonaldDuck one counts votes from anonymous users, those that don't have accounts, the other votes from registered users.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I feel sad if someone downvotes my answer (especially if they don't comment to explain why). I do downvote questions where it's obvious that the person did zero research, though.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow Why would you be so mean to future readers of the post as to leave them uninformed that the post in question is problematic, potentially resulting in them using, or attempting to use, a bad post instead of realizing that it isn't a good post from the start.

Comment: @Servy Downvoting is not the only option to "help" feature readers. You can upvote all other answers and the result is "the same". Unless the answer is completly wrong I find no reason to downvote an answer that may help OP. Remember that OP may have a different opinion on what is correct than what is the best solution. Somtimes a more complex solution with looping and all that may help with another problem at the same time.

Comment: @Andreas I never said that downvoting was the *only* way to help.  But downvoting answers that aren't helpful *is* helpful, and refusing to downvote an answer that isn't helpful means that you're being *less helpful* than someone who *is* downvoting bad posts.  By not indicating that bad posts are bad, people are going to, at best, waste time also figuring out that they're bad, and at worst, using them because they aren't able to figure out that they're bad.  If someone else has their own opinion, they can reflect it in their own vote, you should use your vote to reflect your views.

Comment: @Servy You are avoiding the subject. Your downvote may lead to a deleted answer that works. It's perhaps not the best solution but it may help OP or future viewers. As an example a question can be "how can I produce this array structure" and an answer creating a better more optimized array is downvoted because it does not match OPs question. How can someone else than OP be the judge on what is right or wrong (unless obvious stuff). Your downvote may lead to OP not even seeing the best answer because that answerer deletes his answer for being downvoted.So downvoting may mean you are not helpful

Comment: If you think the answer is actually a good answer, then sure, don't downvote it.  But refusing to downvote answers *that you think are bad answers, and that aren't helpful* is being harmful.  If you personally feel that you're not qualified to judge the quality of an answer, then by all means, refrain from voting (and likewise, don't upvote answers if you don't feel that you're in a position to judge their quality).  If you refuse to ever downvote a post out of fear that you might be wrong, then why don't you refuse to upvote posts, out of fear that you might be wrong?

Comment: @Servy. This kind of argument only really works for posts which end up with a negative score. The most "harmful" posts are usually much less obviously bad, and they can often have a large positive score, even though they also receive a large number of downvotes. Most users can't see these downvotes (because they have < 1000 rep). So I think downvoting can be far less helpful than you suggest. If nobody ever bothers to explain *why* a post is bad (either in comments or answers), all those hidden downvotes become worse than useless.

Comment: @ekhumoro So you think downvoting bad posts is bad because people are going to upvote those bad posts anyway, so it won't matter?  Even if that's true, it's not a reason to refrain from downvoting bad posts, it's a reason to encourage other people to downvote bad posts, instead of telling people that they should refuse to downvote bad posts, and refusing to downvote bad posts yourself.  You're being part of the problem by doing that, when you could be part of the solution.

Comment: @Servy. I didn't say it was bad. I said it is often ineffective, because, unlike upvotes, downvotes cannot be seen by a lot of users (unless there is a net negative score). By itself, downvoting is never enough. There must be explanation as well. Without that, downvoters are just collectively abdicating their responsibility to the community.

Comment: @ekhumoro You said it was mean.  It's not mean.  Refusing to downvote bad content is what's mean.  Downvoting a bad post is being helpful and considerate for others.  There are lots of *other* things that you can *also* do that are helpful, such as explaining to someone how a post can be improved, or posting your own better answer, and none of those options are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Servy. I did not use the word "mean" in any of my comments. I said that **hidden** downvotes **alone** are useless. They do not and cannot help anyone who cannot see them. Downvoting is a crude, scattergun way of indicating that there are problems with a post. There needs to be a better way of making it obvious to users that some posts should be treated with caution.

Comment: @Servy - if the post is really awful, I do downvote. Some people appear to downvote for insufficient detail (which would be better fixed with a comment suggesting more detail)

Comment: @YvonneAburrow downvoting just the worse, instead of the sub-par isn't feasible, since there's more sub-par mediocre content than any of the other extremes.

Comment: So I comment on the sub-par to suggest improvements, or upvote the good stuff.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow yeah, good luck with that, [but I recommend you to learn from experience instead and save you so many pains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/792066)

Comment: @Servy I think you are mistaking both ekhumoro and Yvonne. ekhumoro is the one that claimed that he didn't use the m- word.

Comment: @ekhumoro But downvotes *aren't* useless.  They do quite a lot to inform people about the quality of posts.  Of course they aren't perfect, but they're far and away the best system we have at the moment.  If you have a better idea of how to indicate what posts are bad, then by all means, propose a feature request.

Comment: @Servy. They are only useful to users that can see them, and most users cannot see them. The voting system is inherently biased against downvotes. They cost *more* than upvotes, but are valued *less* (by the system). One answer can get 25 upvotes and no downvotes, whilst another can get 45 upvotes and 20 downvotes. Both will earn a good answer badge, but the downvotes are invisible to most users, and so count for nothing. There must have been a good reason for the downvoting, but unless someone takes the time to make a prominent comment, those downvotes will be wasted.

Comment: @ekhumoro You can say that downvotes on *heavily upvoted* posts are useless.  At the very least they're far less useful.  Of course, *upvotes* on heavily upvoted posts are also either useless or close to useless (is there really any different signal between a post being +20 and +25?).  *Any* vote on a post with a lot of votes on it is worth far less than any post with a small number of votes on it.  That's just how voting works in every context.  But again, if you have a proposal for a better way of indicating the quality of a post, by all means, post a feature request.

Comment: @Servy. It's not just *heavily* upvoted posts. Any post with a score >= 0 automatically hides all the downvotes. So there is a strong, systematic bias in favour of positive scores. We already have an indicator that gives some idea of the quality of a post - just click on its score, and it will show the breakdown of votes. Unfortunately, most people don't have enough rep to benefit from this feature - so again, the sytem is biased against downvoters.

Comment: @ekhumoro By that logic any post with a negative score hides all positive votes.  Both statements are equally false.  You're still changing the net score when you vote.  Yes, there are some situations where the difference between one less person upvoting and one more person downvoting is a relevant difference, in many situations it's just not, and all that matters is the net change of the score.

Comment: @Servy. No - that is not how things work in practice. There are very few posts that have both a negative score and a high number of upvotes; but there are lots of posts where the opposite is true. The system is very clearly and deliberately biased in favour of positive scores. That is the whole point of the answer we are currently commenting on.

Comment: @ekhumoro People cast less downvotes than they ought to, and bad posts end up not being properly indicated as bad to others as a result of people not actually casting their votes.  The problem is not that people actually downvote bad content and it doesn't help, as you claim, but rather that *people refuse to actually downvote bad content*, and bad things happen *because people aren't using their votes*.  I also reject your claim that there are negatively scored posts with lots of upvotes, they're quite common; at least as common as positively scored posts with lots of downvotes.

Comment: @ekhumoro The fact that bad things happen *because people don't downvote as much as they should* is *because downvoting bad posts is actually helpful*.  If downvoting bad posts didn't actually help, then it wouldn't be a problem that too few people actually do it.

Comment: @Servy. I did not say or even imply that downvoting *in itself* is bad or unhelpful. The point is that the system does not make the best use of downvotes, and so they are not as helpful as they could be. On the question of negatively *vs* positively scored posts, please see the last two paragraphs of the answer we are commenting on. I don't think anyone can reasonably claim that the system is not biased. And it's not hard to understand why TPB have chosen to keep it that way. It wouldn't look good if there was a large proportion of posts with negative scores.

Comment: @ekhumoro You said that people don't actually see downvotes and that they aren't able to actually inform readers of the quality of a post.  That's not true.  What that paragraph *actually* says is that people don't actually use them as often as they ought to, not that they aren't effective *when people actually use them*.  Trying to convince people to not actually downvote bad posts is *exacerbating* the problem, not solving it.

Comment: @ekhumoro remember that votes aren't a vacuum. They affect sorting and several other signals that hint the quality of a post.

Comment: @Servy. Please stop accusing me of saying things that I did not say.

Comment: @ekhumoro So then you feel that downvotes are helpful, and that it's important for people to cast them on posts that are bad, and that the problems are simply that people don't do that as much as they should, rather than that it doesn't help when they actually do vote?  If I misunderstood any of your earlier comments as contradicting that view when they didn't mean to then I apologize.

Comment: @Braiam. Well I don't I think suggested otherwise. But in any case, I my view, hints are not enough. There should be a much clearer indication.

Comment: @Servy. Again, you resort to putting words into other people's mouths rather than addressing what they actually said. Should I assume this is because you have no real answers to any of it, and so must resort to strawman arguments instead? I seem to remember getting into a conversation like this with you before, and I had to cut it short because of your stubbornly blinkered attitudes on virtually every minor point.

Comment: @ekhumoro So you don't think that they're not helpful, and you don't think that they are helpful.  So...do you just not have any opinion on the matter whatsoever?  Or what are you *actually* trying to say?  I specifically asked you to clarify your position, and you responded by insulting me and accusing me of putting words in your mouth for *asking you what you're actually trying to say*.  If you're going to accuse me of misunderstanding what you're saying, then tell me what I have misunderstood.

Comment: @Servy. You can read my all comments perfectly well. I think have stated all my points reasonably clearly and have nothing further to add.

Comment: @ekhumoro Taking your arguments to their logical conclusions is not putting words in your mouth. If you think something Servy is claiming is a conclusion does not actually follow from what you said, then dispute that link.

Comment: @mbrig. There is no logic to any of it. I'm not going to waste my time disputing things that I clearly didn't say.

Answer (score 17):

The major problem with this is that, unlike close voting, downvoting is completely anonymous, and there's not really an agreed-upon standard for when you should (or shouldn't) downvote. That being said, it's essentially impossible to measure how good of a job someone is doing downvoting (unless we also want to create a standard for that and de-anonymize voting) and not even an agreed-upon definition of what this would mean.

There are multiple checks and balance in place for close voting as well as accountability. There is also recourse for mistakes. There are review audits in the close vote queue, so you can get temporary bans if you're doing a bad job. When a question is closed, you know who voted to close and why. If people feel that their question shouldn't have been closed, they can appeal to the original closer voters in comments, the SOCVR, or Meta. Plus there's also the Reopen Queue.

There is no such accountability for downvotes. If you feel that someone downvoted your post unfairly, there's **no recourse** - there's no mandatory explanation (for reasons that have been discussed extensively elsewhere), no way to tell who downvoted, and no "undownvote queue." These things are unlikely to change (nor am I arguing here that they should).

That being said, that's why you can get badges for working the review queues but not for downvoting. There's a way to critique how well you're reviewing, an agreed-upon definition of what constitute valid close vote reasons, and a recourse for mistakes. These simply don't exist for downvoting, so it doesn't make sense to give badges when we can't even audit how well they're doing. For all we know, someone could downvote 1000 posts at full random and get a badge. I'm not saying that that's happening commonly right now, but it *could* happen. In fact, given the anonymous nature of voting, it's difficult to prove that it's not already happening.

Badges should reward "good" behavior on the site. Votes aren't intrinsically "good" behavior; *good* voting is good behavior. We can know whether people are close voting well, but we don't know if people are downvoting well.

One more point: do many users actually consciously seek out badges? If not, adding a badge wouldn't make any difference in the majority of people's behavior and this change would be largely pointless. After all, the *entire point* is to encourage people to downvote more often, and if it didn't do that it wouldn't help.

Comment: The random downvoting costs rep; unlikely to happen. I don't see your argument, as other actions even about posting questions are disputed what is right and what wrong.

Comment: @usr1234567 I'm not saying that it's likely that people would do that, just that we have no way to know whether people downvote for good reasons or not. Badges should reward "good" behavior, and we don't know if downvotes are "good" behavior. Downvoting bad posts is good behavior, but downvoting good posts that meet community standards is actually *bad* behavior.

Comment: Same happens with robo-review and minor mass edits.

Comment: @usr1234567 That's why they have review audits, though. If you're not paying attention when you review, odds are you'll eventually get banned and/or have your reviews reversed or "age away." You need to get 4 other people to agree with you in order to close a question, but you can unilaterally downvote and have it apply instantly. You also can't get banned from downvoting.

Comment: @usr1234567 So given that, as  you've said, those other badges cause significant problems in those areas (even when there are some (limited) defenses in those areas) why would you *also* want to do that to yet another area?

Comment: a) Gamification. b) Indicate that downvotes are not bad per se. c) Encourage downvotes.

Comment: @usr1234567 I agree that downvotes aren't bad *per se*, but they're not intrinsically good, either. Downvoting genuinely bad posts is good, and downvoting genuinely good posts is bad. (The latter actually seems to be happening on a fairly routine basis on some sites I participate in, and there are currently very active Meta discussions regarding that). We want to encourage the former and discourage the latter, but there is currently no automated way to tell which is which. This could end up rewarding "bad" voting given that downvoting good content "counts" the same as downvoting bad content.

Answer (score 5):

The trend at SE is to avoid or mask negative stimulus because it discourages participation. E.g. [negative reputation changes are not notified of to diminish morale drop and frustrated outcries from affected users.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223006/174091)

The idea is thus that worse answers receive fewer upvotes, and downvotes are only reserved for really bad (e.g. harmful) advice. [As long as downvotes cost reputation, the reputation system is not sustainable otherwise.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue/310960#310960)

So, as long as the reputation system forces users to only use downvotes in rare, egregious cases, any feature intended to encourage them would drop on deaf ears because of that stronger disincentive.

Answer (score -9):

Will downvotes on answers that get *deleted* count toward the badge? Right now, you get your one rep downvote "cost" back if the answer is deleted. This could encourage more people to downvote NAA answers and similar crap that is destined for deletion (helping their posters proceed more quickly to answer bans), but then it reduces the "cost" of getting this badge dramatically if you can get most, if not all, of your 5k rep back by just downvoting answers that are obviously going to get deleted at some point (leaving the answers that are just bad, but not deleteable per se).

It might be interesting or worthwhile to make the badges specific to downvoting stuff that *isn't* deleted - sometimes it seems that the one-rep penalty is a dis-incentive to vote down answers that *do* attempt to answer the question but are horribly *wrong*, *misguided*, *based on false assumptions*, or otherwise *bad*. I'm talking about answers that encourage using operations that perform undefined behavior in C, answers that assume that strings are mutable in Java, or other similarly honest but misguided attempts to help.

Comment: See Donald Duck's comment.

Answer (score -50):

Proposal for suitable badge names:
[image]

Comment: You mean *"Downvote n answers"* or *"Downvote answers n times"*? Pretty sure you can only vote once for an answer...

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Yes you're right. I will update that.

Comment: I feel like those names don't suit the point OP was trying to make. OP wanted to **honor** downvotes for cleaning up SO, not label someone as *"Grumpy"* which is the exact opposite.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Feel free to downvote.

Comment: Ha, good point. Will do. Does anyone honor me for that now?

Comment: -1 Because I really want the cantankerous badge and I figure I should start now.

Comment: How can I earn Sneezy and Doc?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Some answers deserve 5000 downvotes though.  I like this post, it made me laugh.

Comment: There should be a badge for 10 year as a member too called "Old" and you can be an Old and Gumpy member :-)

Comment: +156 rep so far for a suggestion that currently has an aggregate rating of -42.  That's an interesting edge case.

Comment: There is no reputation on Meta, @Beska.

Comment: @CodyGray Really?  Had no idea that had changed...I haven't been active on Meta in a while, I guess.

Comment: The reputation shown here is the same reputation you have on the main site (minus caching effects, I guess). The [global Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is a separate site, so it still has its own reputation system. The per-site metas don't. @Beska

Comment: @CodyGray no honour either!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @Andrew. I honor every incoming Meta question with a downvote, as do many others. :-)

Comment: -1 for the answer, +25 for your honour. A gold "cantankerous" badge, it'd be a prized possession for sure. Good for showing off in job interviews too.

Answer (score -77):

We shouldn't design badges for downvoting, that's a terrible idea. I believe we should **receive reputation** for each down-vote.

The reputation lost by an answer should be **transferred** to the downvoter. Why? Because we encourage stronger response to bad questions/answers.

Comment: It also encourages people to downvote perfectly acceptable answers.

Comment: If I got reputation for down voting why would I ever cast any other vote?

Comment: I don't see how badges are a terrible idea, but this isn't.

Comment: Binding a reward system to an action which is completely anonymous and where you're completely free to do all the wrong things... I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Gimby My point exactly - there's no accountability (or recourse) for unfair downvotes (with the exception of serial voting and outright fraud).